# Visualizing an example for the Tits building of a semisimple Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, buildings

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group. The term **Borel subgroup** refers to a maximal connected solvable subgroup of $G$. A **parabolic subgroup** of $G$ is a Lie subgroup containing some Borel subgroup.

The set of all proper parabolic subgroups of $G$ with reverse inclusion forms a poset, which has the structure of a simplicial complex and a spherical building. This is the **Tits building** $\Delta(G)$.

I want to get a feeling for $\Delta(G)$. Is there a nice instructive example where I can understand what the parabolic subgroups are and visualize the simplicial complex $\Delta(G)$?

For example for $G= SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, I know that two parabolic subgroups are given by
$$
B^+ = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & *\end{pmatrix} \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})\right\},
\qquad\quad
B^- = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} * & 0 \\ * & *\end{pmatrix} \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})\right\}.
$$
Can one see the appartments (Coxeter complexes) here?

Comment: You can describe the same concept as a flag manifold, which is (for me at least) easier to visualize. It might take a few steps and proofs to see that both concepts describe the same thing, but you might want to take a look at it.

Comment: The Tits building for $SL(3,F)$ ($F$ is a field) is the incidence graph of $FP^2$: Its vertices are points and lines on the $F$-projective plane, the edges correspond to incidences. The same works in higher rank $n\ge 3$, just you have to work with $FP^n$ and there are more types of vertices. Take a look at Ronan's book on buildings.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you. Is it correct that vertices of $\Delta(SL(3,F))$ can be identified with the minimal nontrivial flags in $F^3$, i.e. flags $0 < V < F^3$ with $\dim(V) = 1$ and flags $0 < V_1 < V_2 < F^3$ with $\dim(V_i) = i$, and two such form a $2$-simplex if and only if $V = V_1$?

Comment: Also is there are difference between $\Delta(GL(n,\mathbb{R}))$ and $\Delta(SL(n,\mathbb{R}))$? As I see it, for both groups the proper parabolic subgroups correspond uniquely to stabilizers of nontrivial flags in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and should be the same.

Comment: Yes, this is right, you can define it in terms of flags. Full flags are maximal simplices, minimal flags are vertices, etc.  As for the difference of SL and GL, it depends on your approach. Tits' original approach yields the same answer. The geometric approach (via symmetric spaces) gives different answers.